# Stop npm while work in React Project, How to solve this error shown in below?

Tags: reactjs, cmd, terminal, runtime-error

When I'm working on a react project, suddenly the Web app crashed by showing the below error message. I have been looking for a solution to this error for a month.Thank you.

````
npm ERR!npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wthil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-26T18_42_00_220Z-debug.log```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XwM0.png
````

Comment: There is probably more information in the logs above what's shared

Answer (score 0):

## Try:

1. Updating NPM

```bash
npm i -g npm@latest
```

2. Deleting the `node_modules` folder in your project
3. Reinstalling dependencies:

```bash
npm i
```

Comment: I did what you said in answer but seems like It doesn't work, I'm still facing this issue again and again. This error  popped up while I was in development

Comment: @thilina are you using create-react-app?

Comment: yes I used this, when I created that app

Comment: could you update your question with your `package.json` file?